# How to handle signals gracefully in the Electron.js application?

Tags: c++, electron, node-addon-api

I'm trying to implement signal handling in the Electron.js application to call a custom function either in C++ code or JS code (ex. segmentation fault). In one of the node addons, I did it using `std::signal` method and it works for macOS but on Windows it, unfortunately, doesn't work (although works on a simple node.js environment). I get the following error on the console when the app crashes: the custom handler doesn't work.

```
[10208:0815/181127.900:ERROR:crashpad_client_win.cc(814)] not connected
```